# My Debian 9 machine hangs after installing the NVIDIA graphics drivers

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, debian-stretch

I have recently purchased an HP laptop (HP Pavilion Gaming Core i7 8th Gen 15.6-inch FHD Gaming Laptop (8GB/128GB SSD + 1TB HDD/Windows 10 Home/NVIDIA GTX 1050 4GB Graphics/Shadow Black/2.17 kg)). I have two graphics cards. One is from Intel and the other one is from NVIDIA. I have installed Debian 9 using dual boot but I cannot successfully install the NVIDIA graphics driver. If I install the drivers following the procedure shown on the website [Debian-Wiki-Bumblebee](https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee), then my PC will hang. If I force shutdown the machine starts up again displaying some error messages and then hangs again. Some of the error messages are:

`[ 3.060808]ACPI error: Method parse/execution failed [\HWMC] (Node ffff962f14df87f8), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT(20160831/psparse-543)`

`[ 3.060863]ACPI error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB.WMID.WMAA] (Node ffff962f14df97d0), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT(20160831/psparse-543) etc.`

Then, I have to format the OS. I have already repeated this procedure many times but cannot get rid of it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due some additional adjustments before restart and boot again. The following file can help:
https://forum.level1techs.com/t/nvidia-gpu-settings-guide-for-better-performance/131660

Perhaps is due buffer memory performance And OS configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not really contain much of a solution.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, IntelliCo CR for your response. I have used the procedure described in the link. But I cannot get rid of my problem. My machine is still in a hanging mood.